# How do I calculate the latitude of an end point given a start point, bearing, and longitude of the end point?

Tags: point, coordinates, bearing

I have a line that crosses the 180.  Given the bearing from Point A to Point B, how can I determine the latitude of the point on the line, given the longitude of the end point to be -179.9999?

For example:

Point A = 36N, 142E
Point B = 56N, 163W

If the initial bearing is 43° 31′ 51″, and my 'new' endpoint is at longitude 179.99E, how do I find the latitude?

Comment: If this is an absurd question, please let me know why, otherwise, why the downvote?

Comment: It is encouraged for downvoters to explain why they downvoted, but unfortunately it still does happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will calculate the intersection of two paths, one starting at Point A using the bearing from Point A to Point B, and the other path starting at 89.99999N, 179.99999E bearing 180 degrees.  That will give me the approximate point on the 180.